# Page not transitioning when function is being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Creating a sliding form using jQuery. Problem is the form is sliding to a blank page. The page that it is suppose to be sliding to is stuck on the first page. Website is here...www.entrilab.com. No errors come up on when I inspect the element. Even with no errors could it be the function is still not calling? The function in question is below

```
$('#navigation').show();


    $('#navigation a').bind('click',function(e){
        var $this   = $(this);
        var prev    = current;
        $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
        $this.parent().addClass('selected');

        current = $this.parent().index() + 1;
```

Comment: I see only login form @ www.entrilab.com. Please show us HTML. jsFiddle would be perfect

Comment: It works perfectly on jsFiddle. The browser is where it doesn't work. The Login page is the problem. Account and confirm should be on different pages. Click the links below and see what I mean @PeterSzymkowski

Comment: There is not nearly enough of a code sample here to determine what might be going wrong. And I would love to see a fiddle, even where it works correctly. If you can get it to work correctly in a fiddle, then you just have to look at what is different between fiddle, and your code.

Comment: Ok here's the jsfiddle, but now the transition links are acting up, when onw clicks confirm and goes back to account. Just great!!!!

Comment: Umm. There's no link to the jsfiddle.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski....here's the link -->  http://jsfiddle.net/713Marketing/Awh3G/137/  New prob is that when you click the confirm link and then the account link it just shows the confirm page.

Comment: @sarcastyx http://jsfiddle.net/713Marketing/Awh3G/137/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues with your HTML. For starters you don't have any `doctype` declared for the page. Secondly you have a closing `div` tag after you close the `html` tag. These are not going to fix the issue but just something to clean up the code.

I am presuming that you want the confirm `fieldset` to be on the second screen. For that you need to chang your css as follows:

```
#steps form fieldset{
    border:none;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Give that a go and see if that fixes your issues.

Comment: Ok how come now my links don't go bk and forth freely anymore?? No if I go to the confirm page and back the confirm page pops up

Comment: No idea about that. When I tried it on my local computer it worked fine. And I tried it in FF and Chrome. The reason why your confirmation `fieldset` was in the second line was because there was a left and right `padding` and `margin` applied to it. So the `fieldset` were wider than the parent `div`. Hence the wrapping.

Comment: Curioua, is the sliding still working on your browser?? @sarcastyx

Comment: @Octavius, Yup. It is working fine. I haven't changed any of your javascript functions. Just added a few styles in the stylesheet. And those stylesheet changes should not affect the animation. Try to remove the styles and see if that fixes the animation. If it does then the styles are at fault. Otherwise something has changed in the javascript that is breaking the animation.